# How to set asp.net roleManager cookie samesite attribute?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, cookies, forms-authentication

How can I set the roles cookie in an asp.net website with samesite = NONE?

```
<roleManager enabled="true" cacheRolesInCookie="true" cookieRequireSSL="true" domain=".example.com" cookiePath="/" cookieProtection="All" createPersistentCookie="true" cookieSlidingExpiration="true" cookieName="_ROLES_">
```